# Rejecting urls using PHP $_GET and .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

I have `index.php` with only one line

```
<?php echo $_GET['a']; ?>
```

If I enter the `url`:

```
http://localhost/test/?a=abc.....
```

I get

```
abc.....
```

but if I create `.htaccess` and write:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ ?a=$1
```

And if I enter the `url`:

```
http://localhost/test/abc.....
```

I only get `abc` (without the dots `.....`)

Why is this happening?

I want to get an `404 error` if `abc.....` string is sent. How can I archieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ ?a=$1 [L]
RewriteRule .* 404.php
```

If the first rule is matched it will put the value into `a`, otherwise he will send the user to `404.php`

**ANOTHER EDIT**

I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question at first.

Your regex catches only latin (english) letters, here: `^([a-z]+)$`, so if you want to include the dots use: `^([a-z\.]+)$` or if you wanna catch anything use: `^(.*)$`

**ORIGINAL** - I'm keeping it here because it may still prove useful to you

Use

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ ?a=$1 [QSA]
```

This will pass the query string on after your rewrite rule.

For more on the subject try [this article](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-rewriterule-and-query-string/).

Comment: `a-z` Actually, these are latin letters ^^

Comment: Bene docet, qui bene distinguit

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but it change nothing! I dont get 404 error if i'm entering abc..... (with dots in the end of query) yet.

Comment: You should get a=abc.... and then redirect them yourself. I'll give you another option in a minute